# Android - Get the image's resource

Tags: android, image

My question is how do you check the image's resource? In my `onClick` method there's a countdown (which I summarized to avoid long post) which on every tick randomizes a boolean. If true, `img1` resource is set to `headAppear.jpg`. If false, `img1` sets to `headHide.jpg`.

What code will I put in the `onClick()` to check whether the picture is `headAppear` or `headHide`? What I want to do is, if I clicked `img1` and it shows `headAppear`, `score++`. Else, if it shows `headHide`, `score--`.

---

In my `onCreate()` method:

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic1);
img1.setOnClickListener( this );

//Countdown method here
var = aRandom.nextBoolean();
if( var == true ) {
   img1.setImageResource( R.drawable.headAppear );
} else {
   img1.setImageResource( R.drawable.headHide );
}
//End of countdown method
```

---

In my `onClick(View v)` method:

```
if (v == img1) {
   //insert code here
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Philip. Study the edits Boris and I have made to your question. A well formatted question, is a quickly answered question ;-)

Comment: It's working now.. I haven't seen his solution earlier when I read his reply. BTW, thanks also to you sir for stopping by and helping me..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not restore the image resource from the contains of an `ImageView` I will recommend you to have separate flag that you set in your if /else and us it to determine what is being shown. That way your code will become:

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic1);
img1.setOnClickListener(this);

/*Countdown method here*/
var = aRandom.nextBoolean();
if (var==true) {
    this.appear = true;
    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.headAppear);
} else {
    this.appear = false;
    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.headHide);
}
/*End of countdown method*/
```

And the check:

```
if (this.appear) {
   /*insert code here*/
}
```

Or you can even make your `var` variable with class visibility.

Comment: I already included in my answer all the code you need, except the declaration of the appear variable itself. It should be `private boolean appear;` You place that just below the declaration of your class: `public class ...` and you are good to go.

Comment: I haven't seen your posted solution above earlier, that's why I didn't get it the first time.. I tried your code, I've got an error in "this." so I removed it. Works like a charm! Thank you very much sir! I really appreciated your help..

Comment: Perfect. Now if you allow me to continue @pok's quest of introducing you to SO. If you found somebody's answer to be solving your problem accept his answer by clicking the check next to the big digit on the left of the answer. If you found somebody's answer well-formulated and helpful you can upvote for it by clicking the upfacing arrow above the digit (most users value upvating more). You can upvote/downvote everybody that answered your question. you can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you do want to store the resource when you `setImageResource` you can `setTag` as well.